# Showing last used text in a UITextField/UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement a search bar, and I am going to need to be able to show the last 10 searches that were entered when the user starts typing.
My background is non standard (a big background texture basically), and I can't find a way to make the search bar fit in the image without looking too funky.

So.

Is there a way to use a UISearchBar/UITextField to show last used searches? Or rather,
is it possible to take the background of the UISearchBar out (i.e. make it completely go away, leaving only the rounded rectangle of the search bar)?

Thanks!

Comment: You likely hood of getting both questions answered are low. Edit this one to ask only 1 thing, then ask a second question for the other.

Comment: thanks, merged both questions into one

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:

*Is there a way to use a UISearchBar/UITextField to show last used searches?*

I dont understand what you want to do here..

For your second question..

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];//removes the color gray background
```

Hmm.. i dont think there is a way to delete/remove it completely though.. hmm.. maybe a customized UITextField with UISearchBar behaviour will achieve that..